# How Does When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2) Polling Internally Work

Tags: azure, office365, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I am doing POC on 'When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2)' polling feature in logic app to monitor the share mailbox. But i have some queries which i could not find resolution in any online portal.

1. What is the internal functioning on this feature.
2. How does it retrieve the emails which are added in the mailbox? Is it based on the unread mails or mails arrived after last polling time?
3. If the last polling failed then will Logic app poll from previous run or only the current run.

Please help as I could not find any relevant discussion online on these topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It uses the Microsoft Graph APIs internally
2. It keeps track of the last successful poll and checks for new messages after that
3. This is not done by the trigger on its own. You can set up [retry policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling?tabs=consumption#retry-policies) to retry failures in actions.